# Angular2: property binding and side effects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

So I have been reading the official documentation "template syntax of Angular2" [angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html) here in the sub heading of property binding "Avoid side effects" i see these lines that i dont understand

> We can’t assign a value to anything in a property binding expression nor use the increment and decrement operators. our expression might invoke a property or method that has side effects. Angular has no way of knowing that or stopping us.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning `'yyy'` to `xxx` in a property binding expression is not supported

```
<div [someProp]="xxx = 'yyy'"> <!-- doesn't work -->
```

Using increment and decrement operators is not supported

```
<div [someProp]="xxx++"> <!-- doesn't work -->
```